# Multiple Joins with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to list out grid view of cities which have their respective country and area whose status are true.
Here the hierarchy is `Country` -> `Area` -> `City` 
.Here's my code.
Somehow it shows an error with joins:-

> The type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect.Type
>   inference failed to call to Join

What am i missing?

```
protected void Fn_fill_city()
{
    EF_DV.DBEntities City_Context = new EF_DV.DBEntities();
    try
    {
        var row_city = 
            (from city_table in City_Context.DV_Tbl_City
            join country_table in City_Context.DV_Tbl_Country 
                 on new { 
                    C_Id = city_table.City_Country_Id, 
                    c_status = true 
                 } 
                 equals new {
                    C_Id = country_table.Country_Id, 
                    c_status = country_table.Country_Status 
                 }
            join area_table in City_Context.DV_Tbl_Area 
                 on new { 
                    area_Id = city_table.City_Area_Id, 
                    a_status = true 
                 } 
                 equals new { 
                    area_Id = area_table.Area_Id, 
                    a_status = area_table.Area_Status 
                 }
            orderby city_table.City_Name
            where (                                   
                   (city_table.City_Name.Contains(Txt_search_city.Text.Trim()) ||
                   (Txt_search_city.Text.Trim() == ""))
                  )
            select new
            {
                city_table.City_Id,
                city_table.City_Name,
                city_table.City_Status,
                city_table.City_Code,
                country_table.Country_Name,
                area_table.Area_Name
            }).ToList();
        gv_city.DataSource = row_city;
        gv_city.DataBind();
        gv_city.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        City_Context = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the error you get

Comment: Why not just join on the ids and filter the statuses in the where?

Comment: Error is:The type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect.Type inference failed to call to Join

Comment: Are the types (specified in the new { ..... } ) on both sides matching?  (is `area_table.Area_Status` a boolean?)

Comment: Filtering the status in the where clause would be fine but i want to know whether i can put it in join clause.

Comment: Yes, area_table.Area_Status is boolean

Comment: Yes, you can put filtering in the joins, but you should put the filtering in the where instead of the join as that it will make the query more readable.

Comment: The first thing I would do is to remove everything you can except one of the joins, allowing you to find out which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Do as @juharr says. You are using "join" in the wrong way. This is the join documentation: The join clause is useful for associating elements from different source sequences that have NO DIRECT relationship in the object model. Source: MSDN. In your case, the entities have direct relationship, it means, you don't have to use join

Comment: Simply put this error message means there is a mismatch with the types that you are joining on.  So is it possible that the status fields are `Nullable<bool>` instead of `bool`?  Are the corresponding ids of the same type?

Comment: May be you are right @juharr,i think status fields are nullable types. Also, i will consider your opinion about putting the filtering in 'where' clause.

Comment: Thank you friends for your valuable comments. I thought I can do it efficiently if i can restrict the conditions in the joins.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Trim() operation is not supported by the db driver...
just try removing Trim()

Comment: The error that the OP posted in the comments in no way suggests that `Trim` is not supported.